# Hi i have wierd problem on mac Could not load library. Reasons: [no leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path. akka project

Tags: java, scala, akka

In my akka project while I'm trying to build I am getting this error also I downloaded all libraries

```
Uncaught error from thread [PersistentActors-akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-plugin-dispatcher-5]: Could not load library. Reasons: [no leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni in java.library.path, /private/var/folders/52/md0sb9l50k3b8rxw4sclh7kh0000gn/T/libleveldbjni-64-1-498021637280856383.8: dlopen(/private/var/folders/52/md0sb9l50k3b8rxw4sclh7kh0000gn/T/libleveldbjni-64-1-498021637280856383.8, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/folders/52/md0sb9l50k3b8rxw4sclh7kh0000gn/T/libleveldbjni-64-1-498021637280856383.8: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Could you help me so on windows I fixed this problem by downloading Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package but on mac I am out of ideas

my code

```
    class SimplePersistentActor extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {
    override def persistenceId: String = "simple-persistence"

    override def receiveCommand: Receive = {
      case message => log.info(s"Received: $message")
    }

    override def receiveRecover: Receive = {
      case event => log.info(s"Recovered: $event")
    }
  }

  val system = ActorSystem("Playground")
  val simpleActor = system.actorOf(Props[SimplePersistentActor], "simplePersistentActor")
  simpleActor ! "I love Akka!"
```

Comment: "org.iq80.leveldb"            % "leveldb"          % "0.7",
  "org.fusesource.leveldbjni"   % "leveldbjni-all"   % "1.8",

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Comment: well i added in my question and thats it ive got only build , and this And also config file 
were is written only this :
akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb"
akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.dir = "target/rtjvm/journal"

Comment: also im gonna add here same code exactly the same works for windows just fine

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding the following line in the config:

```
akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.native = false
```